# Higher Order Functions : Array Filter JavaSctipt

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, indexof, higher-order-functions

I have an array of strings that I am wanting to filter.

```
var words = ['hello', 'sunshine', 'apple', 'orange', 'pineapple'];
```

I am wanting to keep only the words that include the letter 'a'.

```
var wordsWithA = words.filter(function (word) {
  return words.indexOf('a', 4);
  
});
```

how do you accomplish this using indexOf in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns `-1`, if it doesn't find the element in the container. You should use `indexOf` on each string `word` and not on the array `words`:

```js
var words = ['hello', 'sunshine', 'apple', 'orange', 'pineapple'];

var wordsWithA = words.filter(function (word) {
  return word.indexOf('a') !== -1;
});

console.log(wordsWithA);
```

Comment: ahhhhh makes sense! I will make a note about this for future reference. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var words = ['hello', 'sunshine', 'apple', 'orange', 'pineapple'];
var wordsWithA = words.filter(function (word) {
  return word.indexOf('a') > -1;
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[String.prototype.indexOf(searchString, position)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) takes two arguments:

1. First is the substring that needs to be searched.
2. Second is an optional argument, that is the position from where the substring needs to be searched, the default value of which is `0`.

And the method returns the index of the first occurrence of the `searchString`, if found, and returns `-1` otherwise.

In your case you can omit the `position` argument and do it as follows:

```js
const words = ["hello", "sunshine", "apple", "orange", "pineapple"],
  wordsWithA = words.filter((word) => word.indexOf("a") !== -1);

console.log(wordsWithA);
```